# How to center multi-row inline-flex

Tags: html, css

Let's have a simple demo showing `inline-flex` functionality: https://jsfiddle.net/p3mztw4e/

```css
div.c1 {
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.c3 {
  border-color: #0f0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<center>

  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c3">
      111111111111111111<br>abc
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      22222222222222222
    </div>
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c3">
      111111111111111111<br>abc
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      22222222222222222
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      3333333333333333
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      444444444444444
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      55555555555555
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      6666666666666
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      777777777777<br>def
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      88888888888888888
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      9999999999999
    </div>
  </div>

</center>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

While the single-row `inline-flex` `div` works fine and it is centered as expected, the multi-row `inline-flex` `div` is not centered.

### Why?

Please note that the number of "columns" is not fixed. Window resizing should change its number to fit as many as possible.

How can we center the entire content with multiple rows?

Comment: Using `<center>` doesn't make sense since it's been obsolete for a couple of decades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centering the flex contents is possible by adding the following to `div.c1`:

```css
justify-content: center;
```

The reason for your single-row container being centered is that its width is less than the width of the container (`<center>`, which you shouldn't use in HTML5 since it's deprecated) and it's being centered with `text-align: center` (that's what `<center>` does). The one with two rows fills the entire parent container and is thus not getting centered.

Also, you may not need `inline-flex` in this case (if all you need is just the centering). You may also not need `margin: 0 auto`. And please, remove the `<center>` - it has no place in 2020 - it's deprecated, and it can be easily recreated with CSS `text-align: center;`.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

The multi-row `inline-flex` `<div>` is indeed centered -- in its *container* (`<center>`). If you set a fixed `width` on this element you will see this:

[image: Centralised]

If you want the boxes **within** `.c1` to be centred, you're looking to apply `justify-content: center` (and also optionally `align-items: center` if you want vertical centering of the text inside the textboxes).

This can be seen in the following:

```css
div.c1 {
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.c3 {
  border-color: #0f0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<center>

  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c3">
      111111111111111111<br>abc
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      22222222222222222
    </div>
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c3">
      111111111111111111<br>abc
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      22222222222222222
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      3333333333333333
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      444444444444444
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      55555555555555
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      6666666666666
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      777777777777<br>def
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      88888888888888888
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
      9999999999999
    </div>
  </div>

</center>
```

Note that this vertical centering will *shrink* the vertical `height` of the textboxes, due to them being constrained by the text. You may also want to consider a fixed `height` for these.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it will be something simple :)